# How to delete the record from mysql if the user did not update his availability for more than 10 seconds

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have created a MYSQL database which has table available_users that track its user movement using android app 
this table contain.

> user_id,position_x,position_y,created_at

If the user has a record it is mean he is available or online but when the user go offline the record must be delete so I need to detect that the user did not update his current location more than 10 seconds
and delete its record to mark it as unavailable

How can I detect that?

Comment: Modify your "online/offline" check to retrieve records that have a `created_at` less than 10 seconds ago (useful to have `created_at` as an index field).... `WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECONDS)` and have a periodic (cron) task that clears down older records at a set interval `WHERE created_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 SECONDS)`

Comment: you mean by set interval in javascript right . but the records updated using android app and php web-services

Comment: No, I'm not talking about anything in javascript; I'm talking about SQL

Comment: oh we want me write this sql into each access for each user . this will kill the server if you mean that. be the way I need to store each record only 10 seconds then delete it . is it possible ?

Comment: No..... when do you do you check to see which users are online? Whenever you do that, then you're using a SQL query somewhere, probably in your PHP Code.... modify that query to include the first WHERE clause I've given you, it's only a simple modification to a query that you must already be running.... and then set up a cron task to run every 10 or 15 minutes to do the full cleardown rather than a selective search.... that will not cripple your server

Comment: On the other hand, trying to delete records every 10 seconds will kill your server if you have any significant number of users.... you're already hitting your server every 10 seconds for every user

Comment: as I understand from you .you want me to write a php file into the server which will do this process every period of seconds I will try that .by the way thanks so much.

Comment: No, I deliberately avoided any period of seconds...... I suggested a cron task rn every 10/15 minutes, not seconds.... and when/how do you actually retrieve this list of online/offline users for display purposes?

Comment: yes I need to hit the server every 10 seconds my project require that

Comment: You hit the server to log the data every 10 seconds, with an INSERT query; but when/how do you actually read that information with a SELECT query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109572/discussion-between-naham-soft-and-mark-baker).

Comment: yes the driver app track the location every 10 seconds and update the place where the driver is . the clients read the available taxis from the table.

Comment: So when the clients read that list of available taxis, modify the SQL query there with the 10 second check that I posted as a WHERE clause above that can identify online/offline based on your 10 second rule

Comment: I think this way what I will do.but actually I do not need to store those are offline because day be day the server will be more slow